# How to disable some plugins for one page in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, iframe, gatsby

I need to create a special page on my gatsby website. To use it as an iframe on the external server.
Therefore, I want to render this page with disabled some plugins declared in gatsby-config.js (like chat widget)

I tried to create iframe page with:

```js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, getConfig, stage }) => {
  if (stage.endsWith("-html")) {
    return;
  }

  let modifiedConfig = getConfig();

  modifiedConfig = merge(modifiedConfig, {
    entry: {
      frame: path.resolve("./src/iframe.js"),
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        chunks: ["frame"],
        chunkSortMode: "dependency",
        filename: "iframe/index.html",
      }),
    ],
  });

  actions.replaceWebpackConfig(modifiedConfig);
};
```

This works but doesn't solve the problem. Because removes all plugins.

How can I disable some of the plugins for the one page in Gatsby?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Gatsby doesn't have a central place for excluding / including plugins per page.

If the plugins you want to remove from the page are simply injecting scripts into your html, you might be able to exclude pages manually by using the [`onPreRenderHTML` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/#onPreRenderHTML) in `gatsby-ssr.js`
:

```js
exports.onPreRenderHTML = ({ pathname, getHeadComponents, replaceHeadComponents }) => {
  // only applies to `/iframe` route
  if (pathname !== '/iframe/') return

  const headComponents = getHeadComponents()

  // plugins often have identifiable props such as 'key' or 'id', or in worse cases, try matching 'href' or 'src'
  headComponents.filter(c => c.key !== 'myChatWidget')
  replaceHeadComponents(headComponents)
}
```

There's also `onRenderBody` which applies for plugin injectings stuff into your HTML `<body>`. See the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/#onRenderBody) for more info.

Also check your plugins — they may have their own exclude option as well.